# Stop and restart CountDownTimer

Tags: android

I have a `Timer` which it starts from 00:00 nice, but when I want to stop it I call `cdTimer.cancel()` but then I'm not able to restart the `Timer` with the old values and it starts again. I have this method :

```
private void StartTimer(){
    final long EndTime   = 3600;
    cdtTimer = new CountDownTimer(EndTime*1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long secondUntilFinished = (long) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
            long secondsPassed = (EndTime - secondUntilFinished);
            long minutesPassed = (long) (secondsPassed/60);
            secondsPassed = secondsPassed%60;
            tvCounterTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", minutesPassed) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secondsPassed));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tvCounterTimer.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I thought I could save the values `minutesPassed` and `secondsPassed` but then I should pass them by parameter, right?

Answer (score 0):

To cancle a timer do this

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

To restart a timer you will have to re instantiate the object and then schedule it. i will start again.

Comment: I'm asking to start from the timer canceled, I mean if I cancel it on 00:30 when starts again starts on 00:30

Comment: Then schedule it with 00:30